# Get Records from Kinesis Data Stream

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-kinesis

I have a lambda function with Kinesis Stream as trigger. If any failure happens, SNS is configured for the email. This email contains the information such as ShardID, StartSequenceNumber, EndSequenceNumber and batchSize. For this, I have written a python boto3 script which is used to read these missed events and separately process them.

In my code, using ShardID I am getting the shard iterator with the StartSequenceNumber. Then using this shard iterator, I get the records till the batchSize limit so that I get the missing number of records as mentioned in the SNS email. What I assume here is that the last record that I receive using this script should have the same SequenceNumber as EndSequenceNumber in the SNS email but this is not the case every time. This means that if this is not same then I might miss some records.

Is my perception correct that these should be same? If not, then what is the proper way to get the number of records same as batchSize between the given range of StartSequenceNumber and EndSequenceNumber. Thanks